# SQL Server syntax to return a query between 2 given dates

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL Server table that has a column called `statusdate` that's an ODBC date/time.
I need to create a `SELECT query WHERE statusdate` can return a range between 2 dates (a start date and an end date).  I've been told to use `DATEDIFF` in my `WHERE` statement.  Is this correct and what's the syntax?

Comment: What does this mean? "statusdate can return a range between 2 dates".  Are you just looking for the SQL `between` keyword?  Because that's not what you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just do a `BETWEEN`?:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE statusdate BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
```

Comment: BETWEEN is not wise if the data type is DATETIME, DATETIME2, SMALLDATETIME, etc. Open-ended ranges are much safer.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Yeap, you are right. Though it wasn't clear on the question if that was the case, since it was talking just about dates, I should've had make a clarification about this on my asnwer, as MikaelEriksson did.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Server 2008/2012 and the `date` datatype you can use between.

```
select *
from YourTable
where statusdate between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

If you use `datetime` I suggest you use `>=` and `<` instead to make sure you get all values regardless of the time part.

```
select *
from YourTable
where statusdate >= @StartDate and 
      statusdate < dateadd(day, 1, @EndDate)
```

**Update**

> I've been told to use DATEDIFF in my WHERE statement. Is this correct

No you should not use `datediff` for this.

> and what's the syntax?

Here... but don't use it.

```
select *
from YourTable
where datediff(day, statusdate, @StartDate) = 0 and
      datediff(day, statusdate, @EndDate) = 0
```

Comment: +1 Personally I would say "and **only** with the `date` data type..." :-)